# XSLT: Grouping issue on Head element

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

I need to group the data based on  element and populate it.

below mentioned is input xml and if you see there are 4 rows for P and then Head element starts that's where i need to group with following P's.

while generating actual output I need to group by .

I need to convert this-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
<row id="j1">
<name>Marcus C.</name>
<P id="j1_p1">[1] Text</P>
<P id="j1_p2">[2] Text</P>
<P id="j1_p3">[3] Text</P>
<P id="j1_p4">[4] Text</P>
<Head hlevel="h1">
<Emph type="b">Facts</Emph>
</Head>
<P id="j1_p5">[5] Text</P>
<P id="j1_p6">[6] Text</P>
<P id="j1_p7">[7] Text</P>
<Head hlevel="h1">
<Emph type="b">Trial</Emph>
</Head>
<P id="j1_p8">[8] Text</P>
<P id="j1_p9">[9] Text</P>
<P id="j1_p10">[10] Text</P>
</row>
</root>
```

Desired output would be :

```
<root>
    <row id="j1">
        <name>Marcus C.</name>
        <P id="j1_p1">[1] Text</P>
        <P id="j1_p2">[2] Text</P>
        <P id="j1_p3">[3] Text</P>
        <P id="j1_p4">[4] Text</P>
        <Group>
            <Head hlevel="h1">
                <Emph type="b">Facts</Emph>
            </Head>
            <P id="j1_p5">[5] Text</P>
            <P id="j1_p6">[6] Text</P>
            <P id="j1_p7">[7] Text</P>
        </Group>
        <Group>
            <Head hlevel="h1">
                <Emph type="b">Trial</Emph>
            </Head>
            <P id="j1_p8">[8] Text</P>
            <P id="j1_p9">[9] Text</P>
            <P id="j1_p10">[10] Text</P>
        </Group>
    </row>
</root>
```

following XSLT when run with xml it does wrap Head in Group tag but does not copy all following P under Group.

```
 <xsl:template match="row/Head[child::Emph]">
    <Group>
        <Head>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </Head>
    </Group>
  </xsl:template>
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I have tried following template but did not get desired results. <xsl:template match="root"> <xsl:copy> <xsl:for-each-group select="//row" group-starting-with="./*[Head/Emph]"> <Group> <xsl:sequence select="current-group()"/> </Group> </xsl:for-each-group> </xsl:copy> </xsl:template>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`for-each-group` should help:

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">


    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="row">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="Head[@hlevel = 'h1']">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="self::Head[@hlevel = 'h1']">
                        <Group>
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                        </Group>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>  
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

http://xsltransform.net/3Mvmrzu